# Display Sentence in Alphabetical Order

Tags: code-golf

Write a program that takes a string and outputs all the characters in alphabetical order.
Spaces and symbols can be ignored or deleted, but the upper- and lowercase letters must remain the same case.

Sample input:

```
Johnny walked the dog to the park.
```

Sample output

```
aaddeeeghhhJklnnoooprtttwy
```

Rules:

• Any language

• Shortest code wins.

Comment: How to sort upper/lower case letters? Upper before lower, vice versa or stable with the input?

Comment: Does it need to handle any letters outside of the basic Latin alphabet ("English alphabet")?

Comment: From the title, I was hoping I could get away with displaying "Sentence in Alphabetical Order". Or "ceeennst". (OK, "Sceeennt", if you insist on correct capitalization and ASCII order.)

Comment: When you `Spaces and symbols can be ignored or deleted`, does that mean *must* be ignored; or is output such as  `,     .aaddeeeff` allowed?

Comment: Whichever makes your code more golfed.

Comment: Should there not be 2 `k`s in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 2 bytes

```
áδ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wwnNb/v9X98rPyMurVChPzMlOTVEoyUhVSMlPVyjJBzMLEouy9dS51EMyMosVgCgxT8G1IjG3ICdVITg1ryQ1Lzn1Ucsi9f8A)

### Example output

```
      .aaddeeeghhhJkklnnoooprtttwy
```

### Removing non-alphabetical characters

To remove all non-alphabetical characters, this solution works:

```
áδgÆ∞_δ¡
```

It is the same as the code above, followed by a filtering where each character is first doubled, and then compared its own capitalization. For example, the string `"a"` is converted to `"aa"` and then capitalized to `"Aa"`, which is not equal to `"aa"`. The same way, the string `"B"` is converted to `"BB"` and capitalized to `"Bb"`, which is not equal to `"BB"`. However, `"."` is converted to `".."` and is unchanged when capitalized, so it will become filtered out.

### Explanation

I really need more string handling in MathGolf... Right now there isn't even an operator to convert to lowercase/uppercase. The only thing I could use was the capitalization operator, which works like an uppercase operator for strings of length 1. This solution also sorts non-alphabetical characters, but those could be ignored. The alphabetical characters preserves their case and are output in the correct order.

```
á    sort by comparator
 δ   capitalize string
```

Answer (score 12):

#### GolfScript, 24 / 6 characters

```
{26,{65+.32+}%?)},{31&}$
```

Example:

```
> Johnny walked the dog to the park.
aaddeeeghhhJkklnnoooprtttwy
```

If the input is restricted to printable ascii the code can be shortened by three characters using `{95&.64>\91<&},` as filter.

Can be tested [here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyJKb2hubnkgd2Fsa2VkIHRoZSBkb2cgdG8gdGhlIHBhcmsuIgoKezI2LHs2NSsuMzIrfSU%2FKX0sezMxJn0kCg%3D%3D&run=true).

The can-be-ignored version is even shorter (6 chars):

```
{31&}$
```

and yields output

```
> Johnny walked the dog to the park.
      aaddeeeghhhJkkl.nnoooprtttwy
```

Comment: and if "alphabetize" could be construed to mean "ASCII order okay, it could just be reduced to `{}$`

Comment: @McKay The question explicitely states differently. And `{}$` would be equivalent to `$`.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Thanks, I'm trying to learn golfscript

Answer (score 8):

## GNU core utils - 25 characters (29 dropping symbols)

```
fold -1|sort -f|tr -d \\n
```

Example (from GNU bash 3):

```
$ echo "Johnny walked the dog to the park."|fold -1|sort -f|tr -d \\n
      .aaddeeeghhhJkklnnoooprtttwy   <<no trailing newline>>
```

From the question:

> Spaces and symbols **can** be ignored or deleted

I chose to leave them in!  To retain only alphabetic characters, replace `fold -1` with `grep -o \\w` for +4 characters.

```
grep -o \\w|sort -f|tr -d \\n
```

Thanks to Firefly for recommending `grep -o` over `sed`, and Wumpus for `fold -1`.  ;-)

Comment: This is not alphabetical order, the uppercase J should still be alphabetically sorted with the other lowercase letters.

Comment: Oh good point aks.  I must add `-f` (fold) to `sort` to ignore case.

Answer (score 6):

### C, 121

This is quite long compared to other entries, but it does not rely on any built-in sorting or ToLower functions:

```c
j;main(k){char s[99],*p=s;gets(s);while(*p){j=p-s-1;k=*p++;while(j>=0&&(s[j]|32)>(k|32))s[j+1]=s[j--];s[j+1]=k;}puts(s);}
```

More readable version:

```c
j; main(k) {
    char s[99], *p=s;
    gets(s);
    while(*p) {
        j = p-s-1;
        k = *p++;
        while(j >= 0 && (s[j]|32) > (k|32))
            s[j+1] = s[j--];
        s[j+1] = k;
    }
    puts(s);
}
```

This is an implementation of insertion sort with a case-insensitive comparison between elements (using the `|32` bitwise operation). This is because in ASCII encoding uppercase letters and lowercase letters only differ by the 2<sup>5</sup> bit.

Answer (score 5):

**PowerShell : 39**

```
$([string[]][char[]](Read-Host)|sort)" #With spaces and symbols
```

Result

```
  .aaddeeeghhhJkklnnoooprtttwy
```

**C# : 100**

```
Console.Write(new string(input.ToCharArray().OrderBy(a=>char.ToLower(a)).ToArray()).Trim('.',' '));
```

Result

```
aaddeeeghhhJkklnnoooprtttwy
```

Comment: That's not a *program* as required by the question.

Comment: You don't need `ToCharArray`; `String` implements `IEnumerable<char>`

Comment: @howard so do scripts count as a program?

Comment: Written in a scripting language - yes. If the question specifies *program* usually it is required to give the complete source code (which seems quite unfair for languages like C# or java but that's a different story).

Comment: I'll try to rewrite to a scrip language

Comment: Instead of using `ToLower()` on the string, I suggest using `a=>Char.ToLower(a)` in the `OrderBy` to resolve your "one fault"

Comment: You can replace `Sort-Object` with `sort` and you can use `sal` to set a one char alias for `Read-Host` and use that instead.

Comment: @KrisHarper Great! Will look into sal

Comment: Your symbol-excluding solutions only work for the sample input. That input was only a sample (real input can also include other symbols).

Comment: @Sander true, I should learn how to read better ;) Will look into

Comment: @RalfdeKleine Sorry, I misspoke about `sal`, I don't think you can use that. But, you can get rid of the variable assignment with `"$([string[]][char[]](Read-Host)|sort)"`.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby - 33 Chars

```
$><<gets.chars.sort(&:casecmp)*''
```

Comment: Where is the output code?

Comment: You can spare 2 characters by using `*""` instead of `.join`.

Comment: You could use `p`, but that's questionable, so just use `puts`. Also, `$<` is a shortcut for [ARGF](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/ARGF.html)

Comment: @manatwork edited...

Comment: You can spare 1 character by using `$><<` instead of `puts` as the separating space can be removed.

Comment: shelvacu and @manatwork thats a gud one

Answer (score 4):

### Perl6: 26 characters

Sorts output uppercase first, then lowercase, deletes symbols/whitespace

```
say [~] sort comb /\w/,get
```

If whitespace/symbols in output may be ignored too, this is only 21 characters.

```
say [~] get.comb.sort
```

This sorts case-insensitively, keeps symbols (26 chars)

```
say [~] get.comb.sort: &lc
```

Comment: It has to sort case-insensitively but it can ignore whitespace and symbols if preferred.

Answer (score 4):

## APL 16

```
      ⍞←A[⍋48|⎕av⍳A←⍞]
Johnny walked the dog to the park.
      aaddeeeghhhJkklnnoooprtttwy.
```

Comment: This doesn't meet the requirements, because J doesn't come before a, d, e, etc.

Comment: Great job there +1

Answer (score 3):

### Perl 34

Now takes input from `STDIN`.

```pl
print sort{lc$a cmp lc$b}<>=~/\w/g
```

---

### Perl 18

*If output including capitals first and symbols included is acceptable:*

```pl
print sort<>=~/./g
```

Comment: I suspect you can shorten it further by taking the string from input (as per the description) instead of getting it from the cmdline.

Comment: Oooh right you are!

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3: 45

```
print(''.join(sorted(input(),key=str.lower)))
```

Comment: I'm not into Python but does your code remove the spaces en the period?

Comment: No, but "Spaces and symbols can be ignored or deleted", so I just ignore them!

Comment: Ah reading is difficult ;)

Comment: Using lambda saves some bytes: [Try it Online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHRSl1dLys/M0@jOL@oJDVFI1EnO7XStrikSC8nvzy1SFPzf0FRZl6JQpqGkkdqTk55vkJ4flFOipLmfwA)

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 88

```hs
import Data.List
import Data.Char
import Data.Ord
main=interact$sortBy$comparing toLower
```

(38 without imports from standard lib)

Answer (score 2):

## F# (<strike>68</strike> 56)

I'm learning F# so I'm sure this could be shorter:

```
let f s=s|>Seq.sortBy Char.ToLower|>Seq.iter(printf"%c")
```

Output:

```
> f "Johnny walked the dog to the park."
        .aaddeeeghhhJkklnnoooprtttwy
```

Comment: You could just return the value without printing it, so [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##HctBCoMwEAXQqwyBQrswN7CLdifu7AWC/jSiZuJkQALePdLu3ub53IwsqJwQaShZsdUVSr4dsNvMoq9C7@DEfrjnA1I9mY5DjIUOty6YSANo4i8p/5mcLNacz9@fFXJPMkf15jaaR70A) will suffice. However, admittedly I can't find a way to golf `Seq.iter(printf"%c")`...

Answer (score 2):

## k (<s>10</s> 9)

Reads from stdin

```
x@<_x:0:0
```

Example

```
x@<_x:0:0
Johhny walked the dog to the park.
"      .aaddeeeghhhhJkklnoooprtttwy"
```

Answer (score 2):

## C#: 83

```
Console.Write(new string(Console.ReadLine().OrderBy(i=>i+"".ToLower()).ToArray()));
```

## Update: 65

Executable in *LinQPad*

```
new string(Console.ReadLine().OrderBy(i=>i+"").ToArray()).Dump();
```

Comment: You can remove the Dump and state it runs in LinqPad's Expression Mode :)

Answer (score 1):

## J, 12 characters

```
(/:32|a.i.])
```

Ignores any non-alpha characters.

Comment: This task asks for a program. I can see no I/O here. If you are using any interpreter flags, you have to state them - and count them into the character count.

Comment: @JanDvorak Okay, would a function count - `f=.`, or do you want me to add the `1!:1[1`?

Comment: `1!:1[1` and `echo` please

Comment: @JanDvorak Why would you want `echo`?

Comment: Does the J interpreter automatically output the result of the last expression when running a script file? Or, how do you run it?

Comment: @JanDvorak I always run it at the command line.

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript - 74**

Unfortunately, due to the way JS sorts characters, we cannot use standard sorting function:

```
prompt().split("").sort(function(a,b){return a.localeCompare(b)}).join("")
```

Actually this can be shortened to:

```
prompt().split("").sort((a,b)=>a.localeCompare(b)).join("")
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 50 bytes

```php
$a=str_split($argn);natcasesort($a);echo join($a);
```

does not remove non-letters, takes input from STDIN; run with `-R`.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, 72 bytes (as lambda function)

```java
s->{for(int i=64;++i<91;)for(var c:s)if((c&~32)==i)System.out.print(c);}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY/LasMwEEX3@YpLFkUiRNAHhcZ1IHRXaDZZli6mshwrdiQjTVxMcH/dlVNvhpkLwzn3RB2tT0U96oZixAdZd10A1rEJJWmD/XQCnbcFtDhwsO6IKLOUDos0IhNbjT0ccoxxvb2WPoj0D5s/P2WrlX19uc/kFHYUoDdRsX@rKOxCoF5IaUsh9N3v44PMcysPfWRzVv7Cqk0oFlpmw5hNpPby3STSDLwJnZPu7PT5BZL/rk5psXz3lXM9fqipTQGuDAp/BPvb2lKo1XIuMYx/)

But since it's an old challenge stating full program:

## Java 10, 126 bytes (as full program)

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){for(int i=64;++i<91;)for(var c:a[0].toCharArray())if((c&~32)==i)System.out.print(c);}}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##HYxNC4JAFAD/yjvFLpL0RVDmIboFnTyKh8e66tPclfVliNhf36zbMAxT44DrOm@8J8PaFag0PKaekUnBYCmHFsmIhB2ZMs1QToV1YmmB4uMhCgK6nLaR/MkBHagzppssZHur0F2dw1FISYUQavXZ72Qck0zGnnUb2heH3TJloWQ0z977u62MGeGNz0bnwJWG3JbA9o8duib8Ag)

**Explanation:**

```java
interface M{                        // Class
  static void main(String[]a){      //  Mandatory main method
    for(int i=64;++i<91;)           //   Loop over the uppercase alphabet
      for(var c:a[0].toCharArray()) //    Inner loop over the characters of the input
        if((c&~32)                  //     If the current character converted to uppercase,
                  ==i)              //     equals the current letter of the alphabet
          System.out.print(c);}}    //      Print the character of the input-loop
```

Answer (score 0):

#### R, 48 characters

```
cat(sort(unlist(strsplit(scan(,""),""))),sep="")
```

Example usage:

```
> cat(sort(unlist(strsplit(scan(,""),""))),sep="")
1: Johnny walked the dog to the park.
8: 
Read 7 items
.aaddeeeghhhJkklnnoooprtttwy
```

Answer (score 0):

### q/k4 (3? 5? 8?)

if it's sufficient to enter the code and the input directly into the REPL, it's just `asc`:

```
q)asc"Johnny walked the dog to the park."
`s#"      .Jaaddeeeghhhkklnnoooprtttwy"
```

the `` `s# `` is bit of q notation that indicates that the string is in sorted order (can be binary searched, etc.). if it has to go, that costs two characters, making five:

```
q)`#asc"Johnny walked the dog to the park."
"      .Jaaddeeeghhhkklnnoooprtttwy"
```

if you want it provided on stdin, it's time to switch to k4 (and we get rid of the `` `s# `` for free), and it's an eight-character solution:

```
  x@<x:0:0
Johnny walked the dog to the park.
"      .Jaaddeeeghhhkklnnoooprtttwy"
```

that one, btw, will work as a code file exactly as is (still eight characters, since q is fine with not having the final newline in a code file). normally there would be issues with a welcome banner and with the REPL staying open, but if you pass the input as a herestring, all that goes away:

```
$ cat asc.k
x@<x:0:0
$ q asc.k<<<'Johnny walked the dog to the park.'
"\n      .Jaaddeeeghhhkklnnoooprtttwy"
$
```

not actually sure where that extra newline in the output is coming from....

Answer (score 0):

## Jelly, 3 bytes

```
ŒlÞ
```

My first Jelly solution on this site! Thanks to @LeakyNun and @ErikTheOutgolfer for teaching me how to use Jelly and @Dennis for making it! :D

#### Explanation

```
ŒlÞ
  Þ Sort using the function to its left
Œl  Converts to lowercase (because it's sort alphabetically, not by codepoint)
```

Alternatively, `ŒuÞ` does the exact same thing except converting to uppercase instead.

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 36 bytes

```powershell
-join($args-split'\W|(.)'-ne''|sort)
```

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

-join($args-split'\W|(.)'-ne''|sort)

}

@(
    ,("Johnny walked the dog to the park.", "aaddeeeghhhJkklnnoooprtttwy")
) | % {
    $s,$expected = $_
    $result = &$f $s
    "$("$result"-eq"$expected"): $result"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: aaddeeeghhhJkklnnoooprtttwy
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>3</s> 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Σl
```

Ignores non-letter characters, so some are leading and some are trailing.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3OKc///j6hS88jPy8ioVyhNzslNTFEoyUhVS8tMVSvLBzILEomw9hbo4AA).

A version which removes non-letter characters is **3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)** instead:

```
áΣl
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MJzi3P@/4@rU/DKz8jLq1QoT8zJTk1RKMlIVUjJT1coyQczCxKLsvUU6uIA).

**Explanation:**

```python
á    # Optional: only leave the letters ([a-zA-Z]) of the (implicit) input-string
 Σ   # Sort the characters in the string by (sorted by their ASCII unicode value):
  l  #  Their lowercase equivalent (in case of the letters)
     # (And output the result implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 34 bytes

```julia
s->join(sort([s...],by=lowercase))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcrNCYAgGADQVcSTQgkNUAO0QnSw1PzDT9Qwp7fo9g7P3t7w6elq7nlcLJhAMqRCtswY24ejzR6qTCfPktIekwmFKIJX0CE0VLl3UqCiJRJwoQI/I0@O4a@/)

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 20 bytes

```arturo
$=>[arrange&=>lower]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?zqmp6w)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 9 bytes

```
/:tolower
```

Modernized J solution that uses a monadic hook.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxUt-qJD8nvzy1CMK_6azJlZqcka-QpqAeV6fglZ-Rl1epUJ6Yk52aolCSkaqQkp-uUJIPZhYkFmXrKdTFqcN1OBYE5KQWq0OMWrAAQgMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Simply sorts by lowercase

```
ñv
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=8XY&input=IkpvaG5ueSB3YWxrZWQgdGhlIGRvZyB0byB0aGUgcGFyay4i)

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 90 bytes

Not the best Java answer, but i tried to use only inline Stream.

Since the rules aren't clear regarding special characters, here are multiple solutions:

```java
s->s.chars().boxed().sorted((a,b)->a%32-b%32).map(e->""+(char)(e*1)).reduce("",(a,b)->a+b)
```

returns the correct order for letters, but with special characters mixed in between:

```java
      aaddeeeghhhJkklnn.oooprtttwy
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDNTsMwDMfveworElLC2kjAjWnjPsGJI@LgNl7bNU1Kku5DaEduPAK83F5kZF2LhIQPtmX5b//sNW4wXav61HaZrnLINXoPT1gZeJ9MACoTyK0wJ3jEJlMYqxDtObjKFLDiQ@LFLNYPZ4UPGOKgoV1fwvzk04WXeYnOcyEzuyMVo7cuxIRjkol0gVd3t2kWnZANtpzSBWNTftYITtc3QkhHqsuJM5aMkmkmTrPz2oF/2L6xlQLaoB4BW3TYJCM37VrK42bx9xxHvtMB5gO1XPFe1t8Wm/Y@UCNtF2Qb24M2nI@DJL11qD2/TBAP7Pj1AeyeHb8/gYnpUP790T@wTXz5APvyCugKP8L1ZwBb2tKYPWxR16QglATKFhBsn0bOWjKABIBBb4hKEVFRluWyrrUx0lrbuhDCds9gRDmcfgA)

---

Another solution (**98 bytes**)

```java
s->s.chars().mapToObj(e->""+(char)e).sorted((a,b)->a.compareToIgnoreCase(b)).reduce("",(a,b)->a+b)
```

returns the correct order for letters, with special characters separated from the letters:

```java
      .aaddeeeghhhJkklnnoooprtttwy
```

---

And a third solution (**122 bytes**)

```java
s->s.chars().filter(e->e>64&e<91|e>96&e<123).boxed().sorted((a,b)->a%32-b%32).map(e->""+(char)(e*1)).reduce("",(a,b)->a+b)
```

returns only the letters, in correct order:

```java
aaddeeeghhhJkklnnoooprtttwy
```